# Could not start com.apple.debugserver?

Tags: iphone, debugging

I was using the command idevicedebug . First it works well on iPhone 5c with iOS version 7.1 something & then i run it on iPhone 5s i get the following error. Why ?

```
Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
Please make sure to mount the developer disk image first:
1) Get the iOS version from `ideviceinfo -k ProductVersion`.
2) Find the matching iPhoneOS DeveloperDiskImage.dmg files.
3) Run `ideviceimagemounter` with the above path.
```

Command which i was using is

```
 idevicedebug run bundleid
```

Why is it so ? How do i solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to use libimobiledevice tools on a device, first you will need to make sure that it is mounted with a developer image.

**There are two ways to do that:**

1. Run any Xcode project on device, it will mount it automatically upon launching the app.
2. libimobiledevice has multiple tools. One of them is 'ideviceimagemounter', use it to mount the proper ios version developer image on device. The developer image for 7.1 should be in the following path:

> Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSup‌​port/7.1/

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me:

> Step 1: Quit the XCode
>
> Step 2: Reopen XCode
>
> Step 3: Clean and build
>
> Step 4: Run again